# Is integer part of Markov random process Markovian

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-process

I have this problem to solve.

Is the process [$\xi_k$], $k \in N:=\{n1<n2<...\}$ Markovian, where $\xi_t, t \in \mathbb{R}$ is random Markov process. [y] is the integer part of y.

I don't know, how to start solving this.

I have such definition of Markov process:

Random process $\xi_t$ is a Markov process if $ P(AB|\mathcal{F}_{=t}) = P(A|\mathcal{F}_{=t})P(B|\mathcal{F}_{=t}) \: \forall t\in T,\:A\in\mathcal{F}_{\leq t},\:B\in\mathcal{F}_{\geq t}$.

Where $\mathcal{F}_{\geq t}$ is $\sigma$-algebra: $\mathcal{F}_{\geq t} := \sigma \{\xi_s,s\geq t \in T\}$

I don't know: the fact that we use $\xi_k$, where k from set of integers makes our process a discrete-time Markovian process? I think new step will be to rewrite our σ-algebras $F_{≥t}$ for new process $[\xi_k]$
Thank you!

Comment: The key here is to simplify.  Try making the original $X_t$ a continuous time Markov chain with 3 states labeled $\{0, 0.5, 1\}$.

Comment: @Michael in this case, the new one will be a process with 2 states {0,1}. But i don't understand how to deal with it. How to connect new process with the old one, and how to check the Markov property for the new (like do we new $\sigma$-algebras?)

Comment: The point of this simplification is to show that the new process is _not necessarily_ a Markov process.

Answer (score 3):

Not necessarily.

**Counter-example.** Consider a process $\xi(t)$ that jumps: i) from  $0.5$ to $0$ with probability $1$; ii) from $0$ to $1$ with probability $1$; and iii) from $1$ to $0.5$ with probability $1$.

The instants of jump are indexed by the elements of $N$.

**Remark.** $\left(\xi(t)\right)$ is a Markov process (you may consider its right-continuous version).

In this case, $$0=\mathbb{P}\left(\left[\xi_{k+1}\right]=1\left|\left[\xi_k\right]=0,\left[\xi_{k-1}\right]=1 \right.\right)\neq\mathbb{P}\left(\left[\xi_{k+1}\right]=1\left|\left[\xi_k\right]=0,\left[\xi_{k-1}\right]=0 \right.\right)=1.$$

Therefore, $\left[\xi_k\right]$ is not Markov.